# want to change the line length

Tags: line, parallel

I have a line which is 709 meter long. I need the same line with 750m long. I mean the same line that I need the same direction.

Can I solve this with QGIS Desktop 2.16.1?

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the software you are using.

Comment: yes, I have changed it. :)